# css, transparent text with opaque background

Tags: css

is it possible to write transparent text over a colored background, like on the image below, with css only ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: As you can see on this website (you could post a link, which is http://www.thechiaco.com.au/) it's an image with transparent text, and you won't be able to do it with css. I'd try svg and masking to achieve it programmatically, but i'm not really sure it's possible this way.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Cause there is still a white background behind, you have to cut the layer under the text.

Best solution is using an image, i think.

Comment: isn't there a solution with SVG like here : http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/  ?

Comment: then you have to include the image twice, the image in the text will not fit with your background image

Comment: you cant use an image (white layer with "holes")?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/) shows a way to use an image as fill pattern for text, using inline svg in the html. I guess it isn't exactly what you're after, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this..

html

```
 <h1>SAMPLE TEXT</h1>
```

and css

```
h1
{
 background: red;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; //for chrome only
}
```