# WPF transparent text with opaque background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need transparent text with opaque background with WPF/XAML. Is that possible?

Here is an example, but I don't use css: [css, transparent text with opaque background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364855/css-transparent-text-with-opaque-background)

Maybe there is a manner in order to produce transparent text with opaque background with c#?

The background should be an Image, I tried it with a Canvas:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- shows only a black box, but should show red text on black background-->
    <Canvas Width="100" Height="20" Background="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Text="My text" Foreground="#00000000" Background="#FF000000"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry for not accepting any answer. My Project has changed and I could not test any of the answers.
If something worked, please add a comment!

Answer (score 2):

You can set it using the `Opacity` property on the `SolidColorBrush`. It takes values from 0 to 1. Where `0` is complete transparency and `1` complete opacity. But if you set the text transparent then what you will see is the background of the text box. In the example I've set partial opacity so you can see the text is greyish.

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100">
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.25" Color="Black"/>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```

Other thing to get the transparency and see the background of the control beneath the text block is to set transparent foreground and partially transparent background.

Comment: Partially transparent background would be great, you could see the red canvas behind respectively the picture behind. But this transparency has to be cut out with "text to Path"^^. How does that work?

Comment: What do you mean by cutting the transparency out with "text to Path". Depending on your outer control the text box can be resized to be as wide as your text. This way the transparency will be only as wide as the text box.

Answer (score 1):

U can make this by converting your text to `Path` and then Make `Clipping` On your white `Rectangle` with that `Path`.

Try this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBox x:Name="textToMask" TextChanged="textToMask_TextChanged" />
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" x:Name="target" Fill="Yellow"/>
</Grid>
```

c# code

```
private void textToMask_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)  
{  
    Typeface face = new Typeface("Candara");  
    FormattedText tx = new FormattedText(textToMask.Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, face, 70, Brushes.Black);  
    Geometry textGeom = tx.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));  
    Rect boundingRect = new Rect(new Point(-100000, -100000), new Point(100000, 100000));  
    RectangleGeometry boundingGeom = new RectangleGeometry(boundingRect);  
    GeometryGroup group = new GeometryGroup();  
    group.Children.Add(boundingGeom);  
    group.Children.Add(textGeom);  
    target.Clip = group;  
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, I've to override the OnRender method and use drawingContext.DrawGeometry? And there is no direct way with XAML?

Comment: No, just convert you `text` not `TextBlock` to Path and make OpacityClipping on canvas or recatngle or whatever

Comment: You cannot use methods in XAML, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.buildgeometry%28v=vs.90%29.aspx