# Texteffects in wpf

Tags: wpf

I would google this question, because I'm certain that it has been answered, but I just don't know how to describe it in words.

I want to make buttons in wpf, like the ones in the picture below. Step 1 would be to just make a white block and make it transparent. Step 2 would be to have a text that "delete/mask/clip/blends" the area that it "touches" on the white box. Where the text touches the white box I want the white box to have 100% opacity. I don't know how to google step 2, thus I came here.

Is this even possible to do in wpf, and if not, any other ideas?

[Picture of the graphical mock up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXlr4.png)

Edit: sorry for bad title

Comment: [This looks to be very close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941864/wpf-transparent-text-with-opaque-background) to what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thanks!