# WPF TextBlock: Stretch Gradient over the entire block vs Line by Line

Tags: c#, wpf

The control is a WPF TextBlock, The intent here is to use a gradient to color the entire paragraph from top to bottom vs the default behavior of stretching the gradient over each line in the paragraph.

Any ideas as to how to achieve that? The image below shows the intent.

[image: This is a visual of the intent]

```cs
LinearGradientBrush myLinearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
myLinearGradientBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0,0);
myLinearGradientBrush.EndPoint = new Point(1,1);
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.0));
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.LimeGreen, 1.0));

TextBlock ReportsTextBlock = new TextBlock();
ReportsTextBlock.Foreground = myLinearGradientBrush;
```

Comment: What is your question? You already know how to apply a gradient brush to TextBlock.

Comment: I'm applying the gradient however the result is that each line has the entire gradient applied (the default behavior). I want the gradient to extend itself over the entire paragraph (textblock area) like the screenshot up top.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942156/1744164